# bat script linking to python script

Tags: python, windows-xp, batch-file, hyperlink, symlink

I have a .bat that sets up an environment which allows users to execute several python scripts for specific jobs. My goal is to create links to the scripts.

For example, the user runs the .bat, a cmd window pops up, and instead of typing `python theLongestPythonScriptNameInTheWorld.py` he types `python go`.

My target platform is windows XP, so `mklink` wont work here. I don't want to use `fsutil hardlink`. Also, I simply tried `set ok=theLongestPythonScriptNameInTheWorld.py`, but id rather avoid the user having to type `python %go%` (the modulos, since it would piss me off if i was required to type modulos). I also want to avoid WSH because I want this to run on native XP installs.

Are there any other solutions besides `mklink`, `fsutil`, `set`, and `WSH`?

Comment: Why have them type anything at all?  Why not just run the python script?

Comment: @Gerrat The scripts are cli utilities which require arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your batch file could take a parameter, and use that to decide which Python package to run.

```
@echo off
REM Set Environment Here
if %1=="GO" python yourLongestScriptNameInTheWorld.py %2 %3 %4 %5
if %1=="STOP" python anotherScript.py %2 %3 %4 %5
```

So, if the batch file is called `foo.bat` they could type:

```
foo GO arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Alternatively, if you don't want the user to pass the parameter to the bat file (say, you are running it from an icon shortcut) you could prompt the user to pick the Python package from a list, with the CHOICE command.

I believe that, eventually, you will realise you are using a pretty crappy scripting language in order to run your favourite scripting language, and decide to do all of this *IN* Python rather than the Batch command language.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to type `python go`, the only way I can think of is to rename your script to `go`.

Or, like most other people have done, create a script named `go.bat`, with the following content:

```
@echo off
python yourLongestScriptNameInTheWorld.py %*
```

You may set the environment in this batch file, then you run `go [your_args]`. That's even less typing for the users.

Answer (score 0):

When doing something similar for myself, I just created a few more batch files.

For example, you could provide a `py_go.bat` to invoke `python theLongestPythonScriptNameInTheWorld.py`

Comment: I considered this at one point, but it just wont do. I need one script to set the environment.